# imagemagick throws converter errors for jpg

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

I'm attempting to use graphicsmagick with imagemagick to resize some jpg and png images. The png images work great, but anytime a jpg image is downloaded or saved i get an error.

I am running this on a windows 8.1, and i've installed ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick using the ImageMagick-6.9.1-10-Q16-x64-dll.exe and GraphicsMagick-1.3.21-Q16-win64-dll.exe through node.js.

Thanks in advance!

**Command Prompt:**

> Error: Command failed: convert.exe: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80 C:\Users\user\Pictures\testA.jpg @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322.convert.exe: no images defined C:\Users\user\Pictures\testB.jpg @error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.

**Code:**

```
gm('C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\testA.jpg')
            .resize(640, '>')
            .write('C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\testB.jpg', function(error){
                if(!error){
                console.log('Success')
                }else{
                console.log(error)
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have both libjpeg version 8.0 and version 9.0 installed.  ImageMagick is finding the header files from one and the executable files from the other.  You neeed to find libjpeg-8.0, uninstall it, then reinstall ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick.

Comment: Thank you this has shed some light on it. I had actually installed libjpeg-turbo. Do you suggest i reinstall libjpeg turb, imagemagick, and graphicksmagick, or should i go with libjpeg-8.0?

Comment: sidenote: i did not have these issues when using libjpeg-turbo originally, it was only when i started adding several other image related packages that it started going screwy

Comment: Libjpeg-turbo (which is a fork of libjpeg) - should work, too.  But you should have only one of 8.0 and 9.0.  The current version of IJG software is libjpeg-9a.   Libjpeg-turbo is a fork of IJG's libjpeg-8d.

Comment: The libjpeg-turbo fork occurred earlier, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg maybe from version 6b.  There are claims that -turbo is 3 to 5 times as fast as the IJG libjpeg.